# grails spring security can not log in user overnight

Tags: spring, grails, authentication, spring-security

Hello I'm new to Grails and have created a simple website that utilises Grails Spring Security plugin. I have used all the default settings, and have successfully set up a log in for my website. However on revisiting the website in the morning I am unable to log in.

I have checked the DB and the user is there and has not been locked out in any way.

Can someone give me an explanation to why this is failing. There's nothing in the server error logs. Here's all the related code...

Config Security settings:

```
// Added by the Spring Security Core plugin:
grails.plugin.springsecurity.auth.loginFormUrl = '/#about-us'
grails.plugin.springsecurity.failureHandler.defaultFailureUrl = '/#about-us'
grails.plugin.springsecurity.successHandler.defaultTargetUrl = '/#about-us'
grails.plugin.springsecurity.logout.afterLogoutUrl = '/#about-us'
grails.plugin.springsecurity.logout.filterProcessesUrl = '/#about-us'
grails.plugin.springsecurity.userLookup.userDomainClassName = 'rootstofood.User'
grails.plugin.springsecurity.userLookup.authorityJoinClassName = 'rootstofood.UserRole'
grails.plugin.springsecurity.authority.className = 'rootstofood.Role'
```

Bootstrap settings (user account details masked):

```
def adminRole = Role.findByAuthority('ROLE_ADMIN') ?: new Role(authority: 'ROLE_ADMIN').save(failOnError: true)
def userRole = Role.findByAuthority('ROLE_USER') ?: new Role(authority: 'ROLE_USER').save(failOnError: true)
def superUser = User.findByUsername('xxxxxxxx') ?: new User(username: 'xxxxxxxx', password: 'xxxxxxxx').save(failOnError: true, flush: true)
if (!UserRole.findByUserAndRole(superUser, adminRole)) {
    UserRole.create superUser, adminRole, true
}
```

Logout controller:

```
@Secured('permitAll')
class LogoutController {
    def index() {
        session.invalidate()
        // TODO put any pre-logout code here
        redirect uri: SpringSecurityUtils.securityConfig.logout.filterProcessesUrl // '/j_spring_security_logout'
    }
}
```

All the rest is default. As mentioned it seem to work fine logging in and out, until left overnight?

Really appreciate anyone's help here as I'm stuck. I have included the log4j logs but have to wait overnight to see if it logs any clues to why this is failing overnight.

Many thanks

Andy H

Comment: if you don't see anything in the log, doesn't mean that nothing is going on :). enable logging for springsecurity by adding `debug 'org.springframework.security', 'grails.plugin.springsecurity'` to your config's log-section and see what's happenning

Comment: Thanks, done that so just a case of waiting for the result :-)

Comment: I was hoping that someone would have come across this problem before as it seems that it would be very common. I'm using a typical server set up too, but I'm sure I have seen it locally as well and this is also tomcat. Sure it's a session issue but don't understand how this would affect it.

Comment: Can you do anything else and just can't login? Could your connection pool to the database be timing out so that you don't have any connections available?

Comment: Yes everything else works... I guess it could be connection pool timeouts but as I do not have much experience dealing with tomcat I would not know how to prevent this without researching. Was looking for a quick solution. I haven't had this problem before with the security plugin just in the most recent releases. I'll do some research :-) Thanks for you suggestion.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I managed to overcome this issue by adding ?autoReconnect=true to the database url within the dataSource.groovy file. So my db connection url setting looks like:

```
url = "jdbc:mysql://localhost/database_name?autoReconnect=true"
```

So my production dataSource settings look like:

```
dataSource {
    dbCreate = "update" // one of 'create', 'create-drop', 'update', 'validate', ''
    url = "jdbc:mysql://localhost/database_name?autoReconnect=true"
    driverClassName = "com.mysql.jdbc.Driver"
    username="db_username"
    password="db_password"
    properties {
       jmxEnabled = true
       initialSize = 5
       maxActive = 50
       minIdle = 5
       maxIdle = 25
       maxWait = 10000
       maxAge = 10 * 60000
       timeBetweenEvictionRunsMillis = 5000
       minEvictableIdleTimeMillis = 60000
       validationQuery = "SELECT 1"
       validationQueryTimeout = 3
       validationInterval = 15000
       testOnBorrow = true
       testWhileIdle = true
       testOnReturn = false
       jdbcInterceptors = "ConnectionState"
       defaultTransactionIsolation = java.sql.Connection.TRANSACTION_READ_COMMITTED
    }
}
```